# If I form Germany, do I lose Prussia's cores?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

As Brandenburg, I formed Prussia as soon as I was able. Unfortunately, France has become defender of the Catholic faith, so it'll be a while before I can take on Poland to get my remaining cores, and I might be able to form Germany before getting the chance. Will I lose my uncontrolled Prussian cores if I do that?

Comment: So can I assume that you are not Catholic anymore? In my experience the DOF is not all that likely to actualy join a war. Just wait a couple of years until the French get into something big of their own and then whallop the Polish.

Comment: @RichardtenBrink: yep, I managed to get all the ones that Poland had exactly like that (took quite a while though -- managed to get most of the provinces to form Germany in the mean time). But I think it's an interesting question anyway -- not least because Lithuania and the Livonian Order still have some of my cores.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is an interesting one. Normally speaking once you change states you get cores or at least claims in all provinces within your territory. I can imagine however that Germany is a bit different, since some of the cores of Prussia are quite far away from what I would consider to be Germany.

Comment: You lose the cores you do not control - or rather, they remain cores of your former tag. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you will not. You will only lose the cores after their timer runs out. You can check this timer by selecting the province you are interested in, then hovering over your shield in the Cores & Claims section.

Comment: That makes quite a bit of sense actually.